# If an exposed structure in a library is changed, is it mandatory for application using it to be recompiled?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, structure

There is a dynamic library, whose exposed structure is being changed, new fields are being added at the end of the structure.

Memory for the structure is allocated from within the library and application doesn't allocate it.But, the application may be accessing members of the structure directly.

In this case is it required for the application to recompile again with the library?

Library is being used on all Operating Systems (Windows, Linux, Solaris, HP-UX etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some libraries such as FFmpeg do something like this. FFmpeg has a `struct AVFrame` whose `sizeof` must not be used by applications, as new fields may be added with only a minor version bump. The library provides functions to allocate `struct AVFrame`; these functions not allow allocating arrays of them. Care must be taken to avoid using an older minor version than the application was linked to; not all shared library mechanisms support minor versions.

I think this is a bit ugly, but if applications do not do the disallowed things it should be OK. A cleaner method is to keep the layout of structs that need to be extended private.

Answer (score 2):

Due to this condition in your question:

> Memory for the structure is allocated from within the library and application doesn't allocate it.

You do not need to recompile the application. The people saying you need to are simply wrong.

Comment: And also this other condition: _new fields are being added at the end of the structure._

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was obvious that new fields being added anywhere else would be a show-stopper...

Answer (score 1):

If the structure's size doesn't change, recompiling the code is not needed. That's why you often see structs like this in public APIs:

```
struct something {
  int public_field1;
  float public_field2;
  char padding[256];
}
```

When new fields are added, they are added after `public_field2`, and the size of the padding is decreased so that the total size remains constant.

Comment: You will need something more sophisticated if the library is portable to multiple architectures, as the size of types differs. For example, have a bunch of spare ints, spare pointers, spare floats, etc.

Comment: Though the size of the structure may be changing, but still the new elements are being added at the end. So, if the old application are referring to previously present elements, the offset should not change right?

Comment: @jilles: he's talking about binary back-compatibility. You can't execute the same DLL on a different architecture. If type sizes differ, you won't be able to use the structure's memory layout anyway, padding or not. (And in the source form, there's no difficulty. This problem arises only if he saves the structure to disk and tries to read it on a different architecture. But that's a known gotcha.)

Comment: So, in that case, the application should be able to use the lib without recompilation right? Could there be any risk?

Comment: Problem is, you only have one source code for all architectures and the size must remain the same for all of them. Even something like `char padding[256 - sizeof newfield1 - sizeof newfield2];` assumes there will not be any padding on any supported architecture.

Comment: @jilles: there's absolutely no problem since program compiled for architecture X cannot use a library compiled for architecture Y. As for possible padding, he can use a nested struct and write `char padding[256-sizeof(nested_struct)]`, where new fields are always added only in `nested_struct`. And no decent compiler will insert padding before a char array since char's size is 1.

Comment: @Jay: the risk is that the application using the library might be buggy and (due to buffer overflow bugs) could write into the (previously unused) padding space which has now some meaning to the library.

Comment: This approach is only needed if the calling application is allowed to declare/allocate objects of the type. If the library is always responsible for allocation then the padding is useless.

Answer (score -1):

The KDE techbase has a good article on binary compatibility.

http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++

I'd say that if the structure is public it should need to recompile. If the structure was only for internal use, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: This is a C++ answer to a C question... and does not apply to C.